# Php switch for multilingual websites issue

Tags: php

I have a problem with multilingual websites... I made some code for my site, and asked a friend for opinion, and he said that server will be much slower when more people are on my domain. He said that I should use Yii or some other framework.. But I'm not familiar with frameworks. :S

So here's my code in config.php

```
if(isSet($_GET['lang'])){
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    // register the session and set the cookie
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
    } else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])) {
        $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    } else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
        $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
    } else {
        $lang = 'hr';
    }


    switch ($lang) {
      case 'en':
      $naslovnica_naslov = 'Home';
      $onama_naslov = 'About us';
      $restoran_naslov = 'Restaurant';
      $motel_naslov = 'Motel';
      $opcenito_naslov = 'General';
      $galerija_naslov = 'Gallery';
      $novosti_naslov = 'News & Offers';
      $rezervacije_naslov = 'Reservations';
      $kontakt_naslov = 'Contact';
      $rezervacija_smjestaja = "Reservation of apartment";
      $kontakt_informacije = "Contact info";
      $kontakt_adrese_h3 = 'Adresses';
      $lokacija = 'Location';
      $onama_krace = 'Ideal for fun and relaxation, Kiwi Motel is located in the breasts in the town of Gruda. From here, guests can enjoy easy access to all that the lively city has to offer ...';
      $vidi_vise = 'See more...';
      $svecanosti = 'Ceremonies';
      $proslave = '& celebrations';
      break;

      case 'de':
      $naslovnica_naslov = 'Startseite';
      $onama_naslov = 'Über uns';
      $restoran_naslov = 'Restaurant';
      $motel_naslov = 'Motel';
      $opcenito_naslov = 'Allgemeine';
      $galerija_naslov = 'Galerie';
      $novosti_naslov = 'Neuigkeiten & Angeboten';
      $rezervacije_naslov = 'Reservierungen';
      $kontakt_naslov = 'Kontakt';
      $rezervacija_smjestaja = 'Reservierung der Unterkunft';
      $kontakt_informacije = 'Kontaktinfos';
      $kontakt_adrese_h3 = 'Adressen';
      $lokacija = 'Stelle';
      $onama_krace = 'Ideal für Spaß und Entspannung, ist Kiwi Motel in der Nähe von Stadt Grude entfernt. Von hier aus können die Gäste einen einfachen Zugang zu allem, was die lebhafte Stadt zu bieten hat ...';
      $vidi_vise = 'Mehr sehen...';
      $svecanosti = 'Zeremonien';
      $proslave = '& Feierlichkeiten';
      break;

      default:
      $naslovnica_naslov = 'Naslovnica';
      $onama_naslov = 'O nama';
      $restoran_naslov = 'Restoran';
      $motel_naslov = 'Motel';
      $opcenito_naslov = 'Općenito';
      $galerija_naslov = 'Galerija';
      $novosti_naslov = 'Novosti & ponude';
      $rezervacije_naslov = 'Rezervacije';
      $kontakt_naslov = 'Kontakt';
      $rezervacija_smjestaja = 'Rezervacija smještaja';
      $kontakt_informacije = 'Kontakt informacije';
      $kontakt_adrese_h3 = 'Adrese';
      $lokacija = 'Lokacija';
      $onama_krace = 'Idealan za zabavu i opuštanje, Motel Kiwi smješten u Grude u području grada Grude. S ovog mjesta, gosti mogu imati lagan pristup svemu što ovaj ljupki grad može ponuditi...';
      $vidi_vise = 'Vidi više...';
      $svecanosti = 'Svečanosti';
      $proslave = '& proslave';
    }
```

And I implement this variables after in index.php, contact.php.. So, is there any better solution? Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from agreeding with your friend about his suggest (Yii, Laravel, Symfony, Codeigniter, etc..), you can create something like this.

After this part in your config.php:

```
if(isSet($_GET['lang'])){
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
// register the session and set the cookie
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
} else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
} else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
} else {
    $lang = 'hr';
}
```

insert

```
$langArray = require 'lang/'.$lang.'.php';
```

and take off of everything following.

Then create a dir where you will create your language files, for example "lang".

Then, for every language file, you create the file needed in that dir and copy the related part took off from config.php. For example..

```
//lang/it.php
<?php

return array(
    'name' => 'Paolo', 
    ...
);
```

then another lang file

```
//lang/en.php
<?php

return array(
    'name' => 'Paul', 
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think gettext is better

https://www.php.net/gettext

but the php extension is very bad, however there are lots of gettext classes for php. just search on github :D

yii, the framework u mentioned, has a good gettext parser

Answer (score 0):

it is a very bad practice to store them directly in a file. You'd better to store them in your  database with a column named "lang", then

you can set if

```
switch($lang) { case "en" : get_data($lang); break;}
```

Where `get_data` is a functional exclusively built for your purpose, and argument $lang is a value (en, de, fr etc) which stands for `WHERE` clause of `mySQL query`.

Comment: But if I do that, MySQL would make so many queries on one page.. It would be too slow, or maybe not? :D

Comment: I have used in and there wasn't a noticeable slowing. you can take a whole array in one single query and then apply WHERE on each array. Like this: if($array[$i]['lang'] == "en")...